# Copying the order of an array to a new array

Tags: java, sorting

I have a Java list of objects which periodically is cleared then reloaded with updated versions of the objects from a database. Before reloading, the user may have chosen to order the list in a certain way. I need to find an algorithm which applies the order of the previous list to the fresh list.

I cannot use Comparator as the object may effectively be in a random order.

Here is my method stub:

```
    public static List<RetrievedPage> copyPreviousListOrderToFreshList(List<RetrievedPage> previousCopyOfList, List<RetrievedPage> freshCopyOfList)
{       
    for (RetrievedPage retrievedPage : previousCopyOfList)
    {
                //reordering, but how?
    }

    return freshCopyOfList;
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Barry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use a comparator, just compare the items depending on their position in the previous list.

```
Collections.sort(freshCopyOfList, new Comparator<RetrievedPage>() {
    public int compare(RetrievedPage o1, RetrievedPage o2) {
        int firstPagePosition = previousCopyOfList.indexOf(o1);
        int secondPagePosition = previousCopyOfList.indexOf(o2);

        if (secondPagePosition == -1) return -1;
        if (firstPagePosition == -1) return 1;

        return firstPagePosition - secondPagePosition;
    }
});
```

Of course, if you have different objects in the lists, you shouldn't forget to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in the objects you compare. Otherwise `indexOf()` method will look for exactly the same object, and won't test them for equality the way you intend.

Comment: Thanks Malcolm - I get a JUnit green line so it works. I don't have a lot of experience of Comparator, so I'll have to have a bit of a think on how it is working!

Comment: I think I get it. It confused me a bit as the objects in the fresh list were new objects, so how can indexOf find them in the previous list. But, index of calls equals(), which I have overridden in RetrievedPage.

Comment: Yes, correct: you should override `equals()` so the `indexOf()` method could know how to look for the similar object, not exactly for the same object. I should have probably said it in the answer, I'll add this information.